# Magento2 - Get Widget from CMS Page

Tags: magento2.2, cms-pages, widget

I have a cms page  in backend, with one widget inside.

Can i get the widget from html content of this page ? Because I would like to get the conditions of this widget.

Like **exemple** :

```
$toReturn = $myserviceFilter->getWidget($html or $myPage)

echo $toReturn = {{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" ... }}
```

And after i can get the conditions with `$filter->filter($toReturn)`